# AIR SharedObject in IOS App disappears after reset

Tags: ios, air, shared-objects

I use SharedObject in AIR to storage some data in IOS App.

when I set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to true, shared objects work fine, it means if I remove it from Fast App Switcher(Fast App Switcher appears by double clicking on home button), and then run the app again, SharedObject with my data is still there.

But if I set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to false and remove app from Fast App Switcher and then run it again, my SharedObject is empty.

The problem is I need to use UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend false, but I also need to storage SharedObject all the time, not even when it works in the background.

Thank you.

---

UPD: some code

this is constructor of the project main class:

`public static var so:SharedObject;

public function Main():void

{

    …

    so = SharedObject.getLocal("MyApp");

}`

and then i use it like this

`if (!Main.so.data.names) {

        Main.so.data.names = [];

}

Main.so.data.names.push(someNewName);`

while app is working in background, it works fine, all changes saves. but if i kill app in Fast App Switcher, and then run again, debugger shows Main.so.data contains nothing

Comment: Can you post code where SharedObject is loaded and saved.

Comment: @LeeBurrows ok, just updated my question

Comment: where are you calling flush() ?

Comment: @LeeBurrows actually I didn't call flush(), becouse I knew that data was saved, becouse when I puted another name in array, the array was not empty(debugger showed it).   I tried to call flush() now - just after last code snippet  - still have the same problem - shared is alive only while app works in background.

Comment: array not being empty doesnt mean data was saved (to disk), just that its 'saved' to memory. i believe that (for iOS) flush() does not automatically get called when app closes. I always call flush manually with SO objects.

Comment: I would also look at your "ACTIVATE" event handler - are you doing something when the app gains or regains focus that might be clearing the SO?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the EXACT same problem on AIR for iOS. 
Using EncryptedLocalStore instead of ShareObject seems to solve the problem.

Here is a link on how to save and retrieve an array using EncryptedLocalStore. Notice the link has a typo - 'EncryptedLocalStorage', change it to 'EncryptedLocalStore' instead - [Is it possible to store an Array into an EncryptedLocalStore item? AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610526/is-it-possible-to-store-an-array-into-an-encryptedlocalstore-item-air)